# Manipulating HTML text by keeping original tags untouched

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

HTML data comes from an API and I need to manipulate only the text part and untouch the html tags etc. The manipulation of text will be done in another API, so html text will need to be extracted and inserted back into DOM once processed. In the example below, the text was made upper case for manipulation which is not correct as there is no way the text can be inserted back into DOM in the original order.

```
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.python.org"
html = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

# remove all script and style elements
for script in soup(["script", "style"]):
    script.extract()    # rip it out

# get text
text = soup.get_text()

text.upper()
```

Comment: _In the example below, the text was made upper case for manipulation which is not correct as there is no way the text can be inserted back into DOM in the original order._ I'm not sure I follow. What does changing the case have to do with the order of the text/elements? What is your question, by the way?

Comment: If it's difficult to follow, I need to manipulate HTML text only without changing the tags (when applying capital letter rule - html tags shouldn't be made upper case). As explained, the manipulation happens in the API, so HTML text will need extracting and put back into DOM - the reason why I mentioned to extract text, I didn't want someone to suggest a built-in method using beautifulsoup to convert all text to upper case